# Showing that the direct sum is an infinite $p$-group which is not nilpotent.

Tags: group-theory, direct-sum, p-groups, infinite-groups

I am trying to solve problem 5.45 from Rotman's book:

> For each $n\geq 1$ , let $G_n$ be a finite $p$-group of class $n$. Define $H$ to be the group of all sequences $(g_1, g_2, ... )$, with $g_n\in G_n$ for all $n$ and with $g_n = 1$ for all large $n$; that is, $g_n \neq 1$ for only a finite number of $g_n$. Show that $H$ is an infinite $p$-group which is not nilpotent.

My attempt: $H= Dr_{n\in \mathbb{N}} G_n$  , or in the Rotman's book we show $H= \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} G_n$ which we call direct sum. I am thinking about what can be said about the nilpotency (or lack of nilpotency) of subgroups of a nilpotent group of class $c$, and assuming, by a contradiction that $H$ is nilpotent.

I am just not sure how to proceed here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Prove that the $n$th term of the lower central series of a direct sum is the direct sum of the lower central series of the summands. This will show the lower central series of $H$ does not terminate, so $H$ is not nilpotent. I'm assuming you had no problem showing it is a $p$ group. ( If you are more comfortable with the upper central series, the result also holds.)

Comment: You deleted your comment. Is the idea now clear?

Comment: Not yet actually. It just showed me not to create more discussion and go to the chat. I am still having trouble showing n
th term of the lower central series of a direct sum is the direct sum of the lower central series of the summands.

Comment: You can also use the upper central series. It is easy to verify that the center of a product is the product of the centers, and that if $N_i\triangleleft G_i$, then $(\prod G_i)/(\prod N_i) \cong \prod(G_i/N_i)$, and similarly for direct sums.